# How to Change Appearance of Text in ChUI Editor Widget

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm using an editor widget to display a longchar value read from a text file.  OpenEdge 11.5 ChUI on Linux.

The logic is similar to the following:

```
def var mytext as longchar
init "Sample Text.  Sample Text.  Sample Text.".

form mytext view-as editor large inner-chars 30 inner-lines 15
scrollbar-horizontal scrollbar-vertical
with frame frame1 no-labels no-box.

view frame frame1.
display mytext with frame frame1.
mytext:read-only = yes.
enable mytext with frame frame1.
wait-for end-error of mytext.
```

When the editor is displayed, the text in the editor widget is "highlighted" (i.e., shown in reverse video).  (See screenshot below.)

Is there a way to display the text in the editor widget so that it is not "highlighted"?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by highlighted. Attach a screenshot. It might be a setting in your terminal?

Comment: I don't think it's a terminal setting issue.  Progress is just highlighting the field like it does for any other input field (e.g., update tvar with frame a.)  I was hoping that making the editor widget read-only would prevent this, but it didn't.  Basically, I'd like the user to be able to move about in the editor widget, not update anything, and not have the text within the widget highlighted.

Comment: For me your exact code only gets underlined, not inverted. Perhaps its a setting in your terminal software...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
/* textedit.p
 *
 * a file viewer
 *
 */

define variable fileName as character no-undo format "x(30)".

define variable fileBody as longchar  no-undo.

fileName = "textedit.p".

file-info:file-name = fileName.
if file-info:full-pathname = ? then
  do:
    message "no such file:" fileName.
    pause.
    quit.
  end.

copy-lob from file file-info:full-pathname to fileBody.

display
  fileBody view-as editor inner-chars 160 inner-lines 52 large no-word-wrap
 with
  no-box
  no-labels
  color display normal prompt normal    /* this changes the coloring */
.

pause.
```

https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/color-phrase.html

You can also fiddle with frame and widget attributes if you prefer that sort of thing.